# Howto make a div appear when clicking link in navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation, hover

Allright, I'm from Holland, so excuse my bad english. I'll try and be as specific as possible....

**Goal**

Have a navigation bar, and when clicked on a item it will show a div with content in it.

okay, for testing purposes I have made a simple jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/hjuekLhq/

[HTML]

```
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
      <li class="item1"><a href="#content1">content1</a></li>
      <li class="item2"><a href="#content2">content2</a></li>
      <li class="item3"><a href="#content3">content3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
<div id="content1">content 1 text</div>
<div id="content2">content 2 text</div>
<div id="content3">content 3 text</div>
```

[CSS]

```
.navigation {background:blue;width:100%;}
.navigation li {display:inline-block;width: 5em;background:white;color:black;padding:1em;}
.navigation a {text-decoration:none;}

#content1 {background:green;color:white;padding:5em;}
#content2 {background:orange;color:white;padding:5em;}
#content3 {background:black;color:white;padding:5em;}

#content1 {display:block;}
#content2 {display:none;}
#content3 {display:none;}

.item1:hover #content1 {display:block;}
.item1:hover #content2 {display:none;}
.item1:hover #content3 {display:none;}

.item2:hover #content1 {display:none;}
.item2:hover #content2 {display:block;}
.item2:hover #content3 {display:none;}

.item3:hover #content1 {display:none;}
.item3:hover #content2 {display:none;}
.item3:hover #content3 {display:block;}
```

The above fiddle is what I want, and not working...

The following fiddle is a working example, but it won't show the wanted navbar.

https://jsfiddle.net/o883h71u/

[HTML]

```
  <li class="item1"><a href="#content1">content1</a></li>
  <li class="item2"><a href="#content2">content2</a></li>
  <li class="item3"><a href="#content3">content3</a></li>

<div id="content1">content 1 text</div>
<div id="content2">content 2 text</div>
<div id="content3">content 3 text</div>
```

[CSS]

```
.item1, .item2, .item3 {display:inline-block;width: 5em;background:white;color:black;padding:1em;}
.item1 a, .item2 a, .item3 a {text-decoration:none;}

#content1 {background:green;color:white;padding:5em;}
#content2 {background:orange;color:white;padding:5em;}
#content3 {background:black;color:white;padding:5em;}

#content1 {display:block;}
#content2 {display:none;}
#content3 {display:none;}

.item1:hover ~#content1 {display:block;}
.item1:hover ~#content2 {display:none;}
.item1:hover ~#content3 {display:none;}

.item2:hover ~#content1 {display:none;}
.item2:hover ~#content2 {display:block;}
.item2:hover ~#content3 {display:none;}

.item3:hover ~#content1 {display:none;}
.item3:hover ~#content2 {display:none;}
.item3:hover ~#content3 {display:block;}
```

I hope that I am clear enough on what I want to accomplish here. When a menu item is clicked a div should appear and the other divs should dissapear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Oh yes, and if possible CSS Only! no Javascript...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this could help to solve your problem ...

try to click on menu tabs

```
[codepan link here]
```

http://codepen.io/amiteshchauhan/pen/oxaBPG

Comment: Hmmm, yes this seems to work, gimme some time to put it in my site. I'll come back and tell if this is what I have been looking for!

Comment: Nope, this is not it, the first content needs to be visible and dissappear when item 2 or 3 is clicked....

Comment: But with a little testing and messing around I found a viable solution: see http://www.oene-jacq.nl/sdouma-html/test.html for on how I did it....I basically used @Amites Chauhan sollution, and will hard-link the the page in the nav link with #content1 in it so it will appear.... Thank you!

Comment: Wowww! Nice one. @Amitesh Chauhan

Answer (score 0):

We need to call js for any event action. and below is the code for showing tab.

```js
$('.navigationcontainer').addClass('hide');
$('.navigationcontainer').eq(0).removeClass('hide');
$('.navigation li').eq(0).find('a').addClass('active');
$('.navigation a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  $('.navigation a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  var id = $(this).attr('href');
  $(id).removeClass('hide').siblings('div').addClass('hide');
})
```

```css
.navigation {background:blue;width:100%;}
.navigation li {display:inline-block;width: 5em;background:white;color:black;padding:1em;}
.navigation a {text-decoration:none;}
.navigation a.active{background:red;}

#content1 {background:green;color:white;padding:5em;}
#content2 {background:orange;color:white;padding:5em;}
#content3 {background:black;color:white;padding:5em;}

.navigationcontainer.hide{display:none;}

.item1:hover #content1 {display:block;}
.item1:hover #content2 {display:none;}
.item1:hover #content3 {display:none;}

.item2:hover #content1 {display:none;}
.item2:hover #content2 {display:block;}
.item2:hover #content3 {display:none;}

.item3:hover #content1 {display:none;}
.item3:hover #content2 {display:none;}
.item3:hover #content3 {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
      <li class="item1"><a href="#content1">content1</a></li>
      <li class="item2"><a href="#content2">content2</a></li>
      <li class="item3"><a href="#content3">content3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
<div class="navigationwrapper">
<div id="content1" class="navigationcontainer">content 1 text</div>
<div id="content2" class="navigationcontainer">content 2 text</div>
<div id="content3" class="navigationcontainer">content 3 text</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: JS is not tagged in the question

Comment: This is also working like I would want it to be, but is is using java and if possible I would like to use no java..... Thanks anyway for the answer. I might use it when there's no way around java!

Comment: it somehow doesn't work on my site...In jsfiddle I need to put the <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> one line before the nav stuff and there it works, but on my browser it doesn't work...

Comment: In jsfiddle you need to add jquery library js url in External Resources to make it work

Comment: Are you getting any issue in console.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code using css.

```css
.navigation {background:blue;width:100%;}
.navigation li {display:inline-block;width: 5em;background:white;color:black;padding:1em;}
.navigation a {text-decoration:none;}
.navigation a.active{background:red;}

#content1 {background:green;color:white;padding:5em;}
#content2 {background:orange;color:white;padding:5em;}
#content3 {background:black;color:white;padding:5em;}

.navigationcontainer{display:none;}
.inputelement:checked ~ .navigationwrapper .navigationcontainer{display:none;}


.one:checked ~ .navigationwrapper #content1{display:block;}
.two:checked ~ .navigationwrapper #content2{display:block;}
.three:checked ~ .navigationwrapper #content3{display:block;}

span{display:inline-block; background:yellow; width:100px; height:50px}
.inputelement{position:absolute;width:100px; height:50px; opacity:0;}
.inputelement:checked + span{background:red;}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="inputelement one" name="menu" checked />
<span>content1</span>
<input type="radio" class="inputelement two" name="menu" />
<span>content2</span>
<input type="radio" class="inputelement three" name="menu" />
<span>content3</span>
<div class="navigationwrapper">
<div id="content1" class="navigationcontainer">content 1 text</div>
<div id="content2" class="navigationcontainer">content 2 text</div>
<div id="content3" class="navigationcontainer">content 3 text</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is indeed a great way to achieve what I want but, I want to use this in a wordpress theme that I am building. And wordpress uses the nav, ul li stuff. Any way to use this with the nav, ul, li stuff? And I'm still missing my menubar....

Comment: I feel its not possible. Because we are not able to navigate to parent child using css selector.

Comment: ok thanks for the great idea! It might come in handy with my tabbed menubar for a specific menu item that I am building